# 1990s ANIMATED Movie in Space with Infection same vein as 'The Thing'

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the name of a 1990s ANIMATED Horror/Sci-Fi Movie set in Space with people being infected and turning into mutants same vein as 'The Thing' possibly.

Comment: Are you certain it's not a more recent one like the Dead Space animated adaptations?

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot:
Could it be [Lily C.A.T.](http://www.crunchyroll.com/lily-cat/videos)?
*Note that there are two versions - one is subtitled English (Japanese dialogue spoken), one is dubbed to English.  Crunchyroll will let you watch either version for free, but there will be commercials.*

Crunchyroll's synopsis:

> 2264 A.D.: The Starship Saldes is sent into deep space to explore a
>   newly discovered planet. The journey will take twenty years. The
>   Saldes' crew of thirteen, mixing experienced space jockeys with eager
>   but naive scientists, are prepared for anything -- except an unseen
>   alien invader with an insatiable appetite. Along with the ominous
>   force that takes over the ship's controls. The voyage becomes a grim
>   struggle for survival in a vessel which has become a coffin orbiting
>   the paradise world which was to be its destination.

Wikipedia says it has a 1987 release date.

I watched it a week ago.  People are infected and turned into monsters after an alien "virus" gets into the ship while everyone is in cold-sleep. At the end of the movie (SPOILER)

> it turns out that one passenger's cat was actually a robot with full control of the ship.

**Though the movie is animated, some parts are rather gruesome, so don't let any little kids watch over your shoulder.**

Comment: Lily C.A.T. is it - you're the best!!!

Comment: Oh yay!  Would you please mark my answer as best?  I think that will help me get more reputation points.

Comment: Good find, and welcome. Accepted answers do earn you 15 reputation, and upvotes net you +10. Upvotes on questions are only +5, but still a great way to earn. Hope you stick around!

Comment: @Joe Just hit the check next to this answer to mark in as correct, so everyone knows!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, CreationEdge!  I'm hoping to get enough reputation to put a bounty on a story ID question I have and still keep enough to comment.  It has been great to find this website and community!  I finally have hope of finding that book again!